# How do I know whether a SQL query in VB has returned something or nothing?

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2005

I'm using Visual Studio 2005 (with an InfoPath form), and need to know whether there is a record in a table on SQL Server 2008 before I proceed.

So far I have come up with the following:

```
Dim one_SearchSQL As String = "SELECT * FROM Employee_Info WHERE empNumber = '" & EmployeeNumber & "'"
dataUpdatesConnection.Execute(one_SearchSQL)
```

...if the above returns something I can let the user update the data, but if it returns NULL I need to check they want to add a new line first.

So, how can I find out what the above code returns within Visual Studio?

All the information I have found has been on passing VB / InfoPath-gathered variables into an SQL statement (which has been helpful for other parts). I haven't found anything that explains how to do it the other way though.

Thanks, M

Comment: Execute() method is used in situations where we are not retrieving data (e.g.: INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE data). Its use, however, is very similar to the Query() method, except that it always returns an integer (the number of rows affected) instead of a collection of objects. If you are using VS, then go for dataset/datareader to retrieve the result of query.

Comment: Don't use string concatenation like that to build your query. It leaves you crazy-vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a function that will return True if any records exists and False if there are no records or an exception is encountered. It also prevents injection attacks by using a parameter for empNumber. Also note the use of SELECT Count(*) and the ExecuteScalar method:

```vb
Function DataExists(EmployeeNumber As String) As Boolean
    Dim sqlConn As New SqlConnection
    Try
        Using sqlConn
            sqlConn.ConnectionString = "your connection string"
            sqlConn.Open()
            Using sqlCmd As New SqlCommand
                sqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT Count(*) FROM Employee_Info WHERE empNumber = @EmpNbr"
                'I am arbitrarily using 50 for the length of empNumber and assuming it is a VarChar
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@EmpNbr", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = EmployeeNumber
                Return sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar() > 0
            End Using
        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Return False
    Finally
        sqlConn.Close()
    End Try

End Function
```